# Sending Email from within docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, email

I read many post on sending email but was not clear with the concept as I'm just starting with docker.

I have a docker container running on an AWS ec2 instance I have a lua code to send email but I get **connect failure: timeout error**.

what changes should I make in to send emails from inside docker container. Consider me a newbie in docker

this is the code I'm using.

```
local mailer, err = mail.new({
   host = "smtp.gmail.com",
   port = 587,
   starttls = true,
   username = "email",
   password = "password",
   })



local ok, err = mailer:send({
       from = "email <email>",
       to = emails,
       subject = "mail",
       html = html_mail,
       
       })
```

Comment: Why not use the AWS SES API to send your email?

Comment: I'm using lua because the container is running kong Api gateway node and I need to send email as a port of my custom plugin for gateway

Comment: Thxs for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You should check outbound of your EC2 network then test your script if it runs successfully in the EC2 first instead of inside docker container

[image]

Comment: when I tried telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 from the ec2 instance, i DID NOT get connected message and the ec2 instance is in private subnet, what should I look for now?

Comment: I updated the answer to show the outbound should look like that